# Azure internal load balancing - Which IP address need to be passed while creating ILB

Tags: azure, load-balancing, high-availability, alwayson, internal-load-balancer

I have created 2 virtual machines and configured high availability of databases (using SQL Server alwaysOn)
Now i want external application to make use of these databases, from the below link it says that I need to create internal listener.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-ps-sql-int-listener/

Found one more article, but it's not clear which IP I needs to send
http://www.cloudcomputingadmin.com/articles-tutorials/windows-azure/configuring-internal-load-balancing-microsoft-azure.html

Example:

- Node 1 IP: 11.240.164.1
- Node 2 IP: 11.240.164.2
- Cluster IP: 11.240.164.3
- Listener IP: 11.240.164.4 (mapped during creating the availability group)

Now, when I create internel load balancer, which IP I need to pass in below script for StaticVNetIPAddress  ?

```
  Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer 
        -ServiceName <service_name> 
        -InternalLoadBalancerName <name> 
        -SubnetName <subnet_name> 
        -StaticVNetIPAddress <ip_address>
```

**Update**

I have used below script to find un-used IP and assigned it

```
      Test-AzureStaticVNetIP -VNetName “SubNetName”-IPAddress 10.249.xxx.xxx).AvailableAddresses
```

Note: The listener IP which you have created during availability group creation will be over written by ILB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you have provided here assuming that 11.240.164.3 is the SQL AlwaysOn listener then you would be looking to pass 11.240.164.4 as the StaticVNetIPAddress parameter.

Just to add to that, you may know this already but the IP address you define has to be within the subnet you define in SubnetName.

Comment: 1.240.164.3 is cluster IP, it's not listener IP.  What IP should I give for load balancer so that outside application can connect? yes i will pick IP from my subnet set.    so u mean i should give 1.240.164.5??

Comment: Oops sorry yeah I misunderstood, so you should just assign an address from your subnet